# Font face, Internet Explorer showing the wrong font

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts

Something wrong here?

Here is the added CSS.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: NeutraText-Book;
    src: url('../fonts/NeutraText/NeutraText-Book.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('../fonts/NeutraText/NeutraText-Book.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
    src: url('../fonts/NeutraText/NeutraText-Book.otf');
    src: url('../fonts/NeutraText/NeutraText-Book.otf') format('opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The relative URLS are correct, as they work in Firefox and Chrome.

I used the following tool to convert from .ttf to .eot http://ttf2eot.sebastiankippe.com/

I am using Internet Explorer v10 and it displays another font instead, looks like Verdana or something.

IE says:

```
CSS3111: @font-face encountered a unknown error
NeutraText-Book.otf
CSS3114: @font-face failed with the control of OpenType-embedd permission. Permission must be installable. 
NeutraText-Book.otf
```

(Translated myself from my primary lang).

Comment: why not using the true type font format `.ttf`. IE9 and IE10 support `.ttf` format.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers may check, in different ways and to a varying degree, that an embedded font (web font, `@font-face` font) is used according to its license conditions. This appears to be the case here, as the second error message says rather clearly.

Contact the vendor of the font for conditions on using it and possibly purchasing a version licensed for use as embedded font, or try and find some alternative font for which use as embedded font is allowed, such as one of the many Google fonts.